# C# entity framework LINQ - create report

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I need to implement in the program a function that will provide statistics on police using Entity framework. The picture shows the structure of the database:
[image]

**My problem is that I can't properly organize multiple Join:**

```
Users.Where(w => w.Region == 1321)
     .Select(s => s.Id)
     .Join(Added, x => x, y => y.UserId, (x, y) => new
     {
         UserId = x,
         PersonId = y.PersonId,
         Date = y.AddDate
     })
     .GroupJoin(Status, x => x.PersonId, y => y.PersonId, (x, y) => new
     {
        PersonPreviouslyConvicted = y.PersonPreviouslyConvicted,
        PersonBum = y.PersonBum,
        PersonJobless = y.Jobless,

     }).Join(Photos...).Join(More tables...)
```

Also, there are 7 tables that you want to merge and count the number. In all tables the foreign key is PersonId. All the result of a need to wrap a list of objects of type ReportContainer. ReportContainer as follows:

```
public class ReportContainer
{
     public string Name { get; set; } // City or District name
     public int? SevenDays { get; set; } // Count of the 7 days by column Added.AddDate
     public int? ThirtyDays { get; set; } // Count of the 30 days by column Added.AddDate
     public int? Bum { get; set; } //Count Bum
     public int? Photography { get; set; } //Count Photos
     public int? PreviouslyConvicted { get; set; } //Count PreviouslyConvicted
     public int? Jobless { get; set; } //Count  Jobless

}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use sql query for this a 7 table inner join on ef will have some performance impact. When your data grows it will be in efficient.

Also you can break the single query to optimize for ef. benchmark and optimize is the best way 2 do

Answer (score 0):

I would get the firstdate so I can substract 7 days and 30 days

```
var firstdate = Added.Where(a => a.Id == 1).Select(d => d.Date);
```

and then Join User, Added, Status and Photos

```
Users.Where(w => w.Region == 1321)
     .Select(s => s.Id)
     .Join(Added, a => a, s => s.UserId , (a, s)=> new
     {
         UserId = a.UserId,
         PersonId = s.PersonId,
         SevenDays = s.AddDate >= firstdate.AddDays(-7),
         ThirtyDays = s.AddDate >= firstdate.AddDays(-30),
     })
     .Join(Status, s => s.PersonId, y => y.PersonId, (s, y)=> new
     {
         PersonId = s.PersonId,
         Bum = y.Bum,
         Jobless = y.Jobless,
         PreviouslyConvicted = y.PreviouslyConvicted
     })
     .Join(Photos, p => p.PersonId, y => y.PersonId, (p, y) => new
     {
         PersonId = p.PersonId,
         WithPhotos= y.Photo
     })
```